# node.js real-time game

Tags: node.js

Is it possible to create a real time game with node.js that requires twitch reflexes. How high is the latency? How low can it realistically go?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

HTTP servers are typically optimised for throughput/bandwidth over latency. node.js is unlikely to be an exception, and HTTP is intrinsically poor for low latency anyway due to the structure of the protocol.

[One informal benchmark](http://praxx.is/post/486034949/comet-with-bayeux-node-js-vs-jetty-and-cometd) using node.js supports this, showing latencies of hundreds of milliseconds. By comparison most twitch games support latencies of no more than 30 or 40ms, ideally less.

Therefore I'd recommend dropping the twitch aspect if you can't drop HTTP.

Comment: I don't see what HTTP has to do with it. For low latency updates between players in a multi-player game, people usually use UDP or TCP, both of which node.js can do.

Comment: You're quite right. However, back when I posted this answer, few people were talking about using node.js for anything except as a web server and UDP support was still 2 months away.

Comment: Ahh :) It's amazing to me how fast node.js is being developed.

Comment: Speaking from experience doing damage control on a project pre-ordained to use nodejs, (and I am *happy* to be corrected!), most of nodejs's claims to performance are based around low latency, rather than high throughput.  Nodejs is nothing new performance-wise (read- equivalent to co-op multitasking, with ALL the pitfalls).  In OP's case, latency is the requirement- so have a go, but... Choose wisely.  In the case I can submit something to be processed and return 'Ok I got that and it looks valid' as a response, I feel *strongly* that nodejs is being oversold to the uneducated.  Thoughts?

Answer (score 14):

It is possible to make a real-time game in node.js as you could with any other language/framework.

The problem here would be what kind of server and client you would use.
Using the [http server](http://nodejs.org/api.html#http-server-146) feature for such game would be a bad idea and very difficult, but you could use the [TCP server](http://nodejs.org/api.html#net-server-183) (now called net server) as you would in any other language.

The client would be on some platform where you can use sockets, like Flash, Java applets or desktop software.

Please notice that even with using a TCP socket server you might have problems with latency for a twitch game, but this is outside the area related to this question and more about [games and networking](http://archive.gamedev.net/archive/reference/list9dc0.html?categoryid=30).

**PS**: You *could* use web sockets since they should theoretically work like TCP sockets but there isn't yet a good support for them in the current modern browsers.

---

**EDIT**:

It seems I haven't explained myself correctly, you *can* make a browser accessible game like you said, you just need to use a protocol that allows you to **quickly send data back and forth in real time**.

If you want a *"pure"* browser game without any third party plugins the only way, like I said before, is using ***JavaScript* with *websockets*** which is not well supported yet by the major browsers. (You could use a Flash bridge and still have your game in JavaScript though.)

Using a third party plugin you have **Flash** and **Java** (besides the numerous less known plugins like unity and so on). Both have TCP sockets (not sure about UDP) and can be made to connect to a node.js net server (with some security limitations). Most people would say for you to go with Flash since there is a bigger support but Apple doesn't like it so no Flash in iPhone/iPad/iPod Touch or on other miscellaneous mobile devices (that support Java instead).

So yeah... good luck with this.

**EDIT 2:**

Websocket support in browsers is now pretty decent so I recommend it for realtime games if you want to use the browser as a client.

Comment: using TCP for a game is not very wise, UDP is the way to go.

Comment: I disagree entirely. Using UDP for a game is not very wise, TCP is the way to go.

Comment: Either way, UDP is even less supported on these platforms. (I don't remember if Flash supports it, I think Java Apples do, though.)

Comment: @Lo'oris, Ricket - It really depends on the game. If your making a turn based game, TCP may be the way to go. However if your making a real-time game UDP would be the way to go.

Comment: @Brian Agreed. TCP just has way too much overhead for real-time. If one (or more) of the users has a laggy connection the server will get hammered with packet re-send requests. Not only will it increase the load on the server but the transmission to the client will be stuck waiting for the new packet to arrive and the data to be re-assembled (throwing the state even more out of sync). The latency weaknesses of TCP are a lag multiplier in real-time data situations.

Comment: @Ricket - list 5 game engines that use UDP as a transport. List 5 game engines that use TCP as a transport. Compare network play review scores. Wasn't that easy? The hard part is client side prediction and that is a BLACK art. TCP is not generally considered by the industry as the way to go due to the fact you're already committed to sending a stream that is possibly already stale on crap connections. A general-consensus UDP/P2P model is in 2013, industry practice over higher latency 'One Canonical Server' approach. e.g. - see UE4/iDTech 5/Frostbite/whatever the StarCraft 2 engine is called

Answer (score 4):

It's possible, but it depends on how much data must be transmitted between server and client and how fast (speaking of latency). Take a look at [Sousaball by Creationix](http://github.com/creationix/sousaball), for example.

Also, if you plan to use websockets, take a look at [Socket.IO](http://github.com/learnboost/socket.io) library by learnboost. It uses websockets when available and falls back to comet in other cases.