# iPhone and Android game server

Tags: android, iphone, web-services

I have to make a game for both iPhone and Android platforms. So, i need:

- **The game logic to be on the server side.**
- I think that polling should be avoided, but I am not sure. (**Persistent connection**)
- **Stateful server.**
- Available framework for iPhone and Android
- I do NOT need encryption because the game will be played inside a specific place. (Location based game) and only one game should be available at a moment.

I have read various questions on stackoverflow and i have some concerns about the solutions available.

- XMPP is stateful and persistent and stateful but i cannot understand how to implement the game logic on the server side
- REST needs polling from the client side.
- My own TCP server is a little bit dangerous to implement. Is that right?

  Please tell me what is the best solution to go with and the frameworks I should use.
  Is google app engine in combination with xmpp suitable for this situation?

Answer (score 3):

Instead of rolling your own use a service like Parse or Urban Airship:

https://www.parse.com/

http://urbanairship.com/

They do an amazing job providing a cross platform push solution.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of polling, you could use C2DM for Android and Apple Push Notification Service for iPhone.

http://code.google.com/intl/de-DE/android/c2dm/

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apple_Push_Notification_Service

Comment: Thanms for the fast response. And what about the stateful server with the game logic?

Comment: I'm using AppEngine as a persistance server for some of my applications. You could try so in conjunction with C2DM, for instance.

If you wanna check some source code, you can check the Chrome to Phone open project

http://code.google.com/p/chrometophone/

Answer (score 0):

node.js lets you do fancy games servers pretty easily, using most any protocol you'd want to use. Socket.io is a layer on to of node.js that uses web-sockets, but their are android/iphone clients. It's pretty great at real-time stuff.

Some links for you:

- [node.js real-time game](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2726120/node-js-real-time-game)
- http://www.nodejs.org
- http://www.socket.io
- https://github.com/joyent/node/wiki/Projects,-Applications,-and-Companies-Using-Node

As for Push Notifications, they're a good idea, but they're a little slow in my opinion. They may be necessary though if you want people to get notifications that don't have the app open.

Comment: So I create the server on node.js and I use a framework for the iPhone/Android side? Do i need socket.io. Is that process thread safe? I am not used to writing server side code.

Comment: Yeah so the node.js is the server code. Sorry if that's not what you were looking for. Socket.io lets you do real-time stuff easily. There are android and objective-c frameworks to help you implement it.