# Simulating virtual worlds: continuous or discrete steps?

Tags: javascript, performance, node.js, simulation

I'm making something similar to Polyworld, which means I will be simulating virtual worlds where little creepers run around, eat, and evolve. I'm making that with Node.js, and I plan to use physics and neural networks, but I'm not sure what's the best way to update the world, more specifically, should the update functions be recieving delta time as an argument, or do the same thing each time, independent of when they were last called? What are the benefits of both ways?

**Edit:**
A point that I have against continous updates is that I want to implement some kind of intervals, for example, each 20 simulation seconds a food block spawns. If the dt gets different than 1 (or a fraction of 1), this will never work precisely.

Then again, if I go with discrete updates, where updates don't care about how much time has passed, I won't be able to "slow time down". As I made this to work on a powerful server and render in the browser, I figure that the updates will happen pretty often, and I need a way of slowing time down without affecting the simulation, so I can see what's happening.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your don't have multiple agents (each with its own thread) that have to collaborate and that you dont have to deal with synchronization/events of process flow problems I recomend you to use continuous simulation. Using fixed time step and change the state of your world in each step.
Each world piece change its state using a funcion like:

newState = f(oldState, deltaSteps)

About the speed problem you mention, do not directly map your iterations to time. Define a intermediate time unit (step), and them map this unit time to ms, iterations or what you prefer. So if you what to increase or reduce your simulation speed, just change the factor used to conver from step to time/iterations. If you need to change speed just change your constant.

Check this [page](http://www.extendsim.com/sols_simoverview.html#tables) with some insight about simulation techniques.

Answer (score 2):

Each time you invoke updating function you can calculate how much time elapsed since animation start. Then you pass this time to updating function and having that, even though frame may not be updated precisely at 20th second, you may make all your calculations according to actual time.

Example: Car starts its movement at 20th second with speed 3units/s. Assume that update function is triggered at following times: ..., 19.35s, 20.67s, ...
When updating at 19.35s you know what it should not yet be moved so nothing happens, but when update function is triggered with time value 20.67s then you know that car has already been moving for 0.67s, therefore you calculate its position (time*speed) 0.67*3 = 2.01 and do all other calculations/draw as if it was already 2.01 units moved. This way you don't need to worry about not precise time measurements, lags, updating function taking more time than usually etc.

Answer (score 1):

I think you not exceed a certain frequency (like 50 Hz). That would waste CPU time on unneeded precision.

If the user's device cannot provide that update rate, you an either

1. Keep the same physics frequency and slow down wall-clock speed
2. Lower the physics frequency with higher delta T

I'd go with 2 if the frequency is still above 20Hz. If it goes lower you probably should switch to strategy 1 in order to maintain precision.

So you probably want a deltaT based solution so you can adjust the update frequency.

Comment: Considering your edit: When a food drop event occurs in the middle of a simulation cycle you can split the cycle into two and spawn the food perfectly precise at the cost of an additional physics cycle.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand... Lets say that the event is set to occur at precisely 20 seconds after simulation start. But, if the simulation is being advanced at the speed of 0.7889835 seconds each update, the event will never occur exaclty when it was supposed to.

Comment: You run 25 normal simulation steps (19.7245875). Then you run a step with deltaT = (20 - 19.72) (it's exactly 20s now), then you drop the food, then you continue running with normal deltaT.

Comment: Oh, interesting. I actually had a similar idea, although a bit different... I still have to think about this tomorrow though, but it seems quite OK.

Answer (score 1):

Your update functions should do the same thing every time step.

There are drawbacks to both approaches, but passing a delta that represents the time elapsed since the last update becomes difficult to manage when simulating many-to-many interactions within a population. This is because it is time-consuming to predict the points in time (the deltas) at which interactions will happen. If these points in time are missed, the simulation is not accurate.

A drawback to the approach that updates all the elements at every time-step is that it will do unneeded work. However, the cost of this unneeded work will probably be less than the amount of work it would take to accurately predict which points in time need to be evaluated, especially given a complex interacting environment.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are going to want your animation to be continuous and based on some elapsed time or clock (that you might be able to speed up or slow down).  So some update functions you would want to be based on a delta.

But that doesn't mean that you can't for example use a setInterval to spawn food blocks.  It also doesn't mean that everything else needs or should be based on that delta.

For example, you could check after your position update for creatures that are near each other or whatever condition is required for procreation, and then generate the offspring as a discrete step that isn't dependent on the current clock.  You would want to record what the clock was when that happened though.

Comment: What if I want to change the delta all the time? Then I simply cannot rely on setInterval, or rely on that in general because it's inprecise. Also, there's no need to check for some things more often than others, but thanks for the idea, I might use it.

Answer (score -1):

I would do this with constant timestep. It's by far more easy to code. Each update function does one step according to environement. You don't have to update the browser each step. You can compute 10 or 100 steps and then send results to browser.

It will be much more accurate this way. Lot of small simple steps are much easier to code than delta time depending functions (a nightmare).

If you are using variable time steps. When time step is big, you could have scenario where an ant is on point A at t0 and point B at t+delta. You update the ant first, it ends in point B. The you update a food respawn point between A and B that should have respawn at t0+ 1/3 delta.  The ant passed by without seening the food. The simulation is wrong.

Other things you'll probably need :

- To be really accurate you must check collision between segments [previous position - new position] rather than points. Otherwise ants may cross themselve without colliding. Check physics engines.
- Avoid to send all objects to your browser. Use Octrees or quadtrees to quickly determine wich subset of your data correspond to the area displayed by browsers.

Strange choice to do this in Node.js, I would use a Java or a real oop language.

You'll find lot of useful help on game developer forums.

Comment: Nothing weird about using node.js for games development: ... http://blog.joshsoftware.com/2012/04/12/real-time-games-using-html5-websockets-nodejs-and-socket-io/ ... http://smus.com/multiplayer-html5-games-with-node/ ... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2726120/node-js-real-time-game

Comment: It's implied from the term "real oop language" you think Javascript is trying to be OOP. It's really not.

Comment: From what I know of Node.js it's using Javascript which is not OOP (even if it's possible to code "OOP style"). I think an evolution game is exactly the kind of program which will benefit from strict OOP design. Nodejs will make it easier to start, but i fear it will quickly endup in spaghetti code. A strict language with typed vars, access modifiers, strict class model, inheritance, interfaces will require more design but makes a much readable and maintainable code. It's not a charge against NodeJs, just a personal opinion.

Comment: Javascript is object oriented. That's it. It's dynamic, but IT. IS. OOP. Node.js is more than adequate for this, and Javascript will improve productivity and not cause headaches.

Comment: @bokan A classic use case for logical programming (eg. Prolog, F#) is this style of game.

Comment: @Bane He said "real OOP". I implied from that (hence why I said: 'implied from the term') he was using OOP to mean 'class-based'.

Comment: Ok then, sorry. But I just don't see how could I benefit at all using C++ or strict typing.

Comment: NodeJs is made for intensive I/O with just one thread. If you don't plan to have 10k viewer you don't need it. What you need is efficient CPU usage and just a little I/O. This is where strict typing and multithreading will help. Also, strict class based design will allow you to create a "walker" class for an animal and extend it with other abilities (inheritance). I think Java or C# are good choice for what you want to do. C++ will leverage more power but it require more attention for memory management wich is lot of work.